# SSIS:sql-server-2005: [ASEOLEDB]Could not load code page for requested charset

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis, sybase

I have an ssis package using the aseoldb.1 provider for a data source.  when i run the package through BIDS, i have no problem, when i run it through sql (xp_cmdshell) the data flow process about half of the data and then throws this error: "[ASEOLEDB]Could not load code page for requested charset"  i have defined my charset=utf8, but still no luck.  Has anyone encountered this before?

server: win2003

bids: v9.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone in the future, the answer was in the runtime environment for me so i ran this:

```
dtexec /FILE "\\path\to\ssis.dtsx"  /X86  /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E
```

the driver i was using was very old and needed the 32 bit runtime, it would run in 64bit environment but the character sets and code pages would eventually mismatch....  The **/X86** param was the key for me.

EDIT: Another very important piece of information:::::Make absolute sure that you are using a newer version of the driver, i was on 12.something and upgraded to 15.0.9 and it fixed this issue.